# How to use regex to print value on angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I do something like this on a template view?

Example:

```
{{ field.replace(/ \d*/, "") }}
```

Where field is a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regular expression literals in angular expressions (see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)). It means that the closest you can get is creating a regexp object in controller

```
$scope.regexp = / \d*/;
```

and then use it in template:

```
{{ field.replace(regexp, "") }}
```

Comment: if you really want this logic to be in one place only, you can use <div ng-init="regexp = /blah/">{{field.replace(regexp, '!')}}</div>

Comment: @ilj No, you can't. One more time: you can't use regular expression literal in Angular expressions.

Comment: you're right. not even with ng-init. but you can have a custom filter that parses RegExp from string parameter and applies it.